# Volume UIControl

Tags: iphone

I need a control in the form of a circle, which will change the volume by closwise and conterClockwise moves

Analog volume slider

Does anybody met this control?

Answer (score 0):

This is for OSX Cocoa: http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/CircularSlider.html

But regulary theese controls are vertical sliders like controls with different style.

After you tap the UIView the control observe the vertical distance between the tappoint and the UIControl. This works great on desktop. But if you work with small places the vertical slider will be better choice.